# Floating Action Button forcing image to bottom right corner instead of center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am using the Floating Action Button with an image and after a recent Android Studio update, the image is no longer centered and sits in the bottom right corner

[image]

I never changed any of the code regarding the image nor the button, but am curious as to how I can get this to be centered again.

Here is what I have for my button:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
 android:id="@+id/expandButton"
 android:layout_width="44dp"
 android:layout_height="44dp"
 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
 android:layout_below="@id/imageFrame"
 android:layout_marginBottom="-22dp"
 android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/item_margin"
 android:layout_marginTop="-22dp"
 android:background="@color/orange"
 app:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
 app:borderWidth="0dp"
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand" />
```

And here is the image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="512dp"
    android:height="512dp"
    android:viewportWidth="512"
    android:viewportHeight="512">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/white"
        android:pathData="M64.9 127c-14.9-14.9-39.1-14.9-54 0s-14.9 39.1 0 54l218 218c14.9 14.9 39.1 14.9 54 0l218-218c14.9-14.9 14.9-39.1 0-54-14.9-14.9-39.1-14.9-54 0l-191 191.2L64.9 127z" />
</vector>
```

As I states, I never changed anything with these two parts and now all of the sudden the image is forced to the bottom right. How can I get the image to center on the button?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code. What I did was changed few attributes.

**For FloatingActionButton.**

try changing this

```
android:layout_width="44dp"
android:layout_height="44dp"
```

to this

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**For ic_expand**

Change this

```
android:viewportWidth="512"
android:viewportHeight="512"
```

to this

```
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
```

Let me know if this works.

[EDIT] This is my code.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/expandButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-22dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand_more_black_24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ic_expand_more_black_24dp.xml**

```
<vector
    android:height="512dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="512dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M16.59,8.59L12,13.17 7.41,8.59 6,10l6,6 6,-6z"/>
</vector>
```

Here is [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wlqi.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, it ended up just not even displaying the image at all.

Comment: @BlondeSwan You can just try changing values of FloatingActionButton to wrap_content. And keep your initial values as 512 for ic_expand.

Answer (score 0):

set

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Please try below code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/expandButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/orange"/>
```

I hope its work for you.